# HTTP 405 Error on invoking controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.2 web app. I need to get the value of a textbox in a controller method so I have this code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Home")'" />
```

My button calls the controller method.

The controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SelectCar(FormCollection form)
{
```

When this method is invoked, I get a 405 error. My host informs me that the server is setup to allow this, and the web.config is set correctly. Is this code in any way?

Comment: `location.href` is not going to `POST` any data to the controller. That will just change the location of the browser window, which will perform a `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

The status code 405 means [Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) which effectively means that you are using a HTTP method/verb for a route that does not support this route. In your case, the action is a POST action (`[HttpPost]`), so you will need to use the HTTP POST method to make it succeed. If you get that error, you apparently used the wrong method.

The reason for that is pretty simple: You have a click handler on your button. So when you click the button, the following code is executed:

```
location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Home")'
```

The `@Url.Action()` part is Razor code, so that will be executed on the server first when it serves the HTML to the browser. So to the browser, there will be something like this:

```
location.href='http://localhost:5000/Home/Create'
```

When you click the button, then some JavaScript code will set the [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to that new URL. This means that the browser will then navigate to that URL. But navigations in a browser are usually GET requests. So the browser will make a GET request to that URL and you will get the 405 error because it had to be POST instead.

The solution to this is “it depends”. If you want to build a standard HTML form, then you should use the standard HTML mechanism to build a form that then *posts* to your action. This can be done using the ASP.NET Core [form tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home">

  <!-- form contents -->

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: As luck would hve it, this is the fix I've implemented! :)

Comment: I did the same thing, but ultimately, I just changed the decorator to [HttpGet] in the controller.