# HTTP ERROR 405 | [HttpPost] ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, asp.net-core-3.1, http-status-code-405

so here's the thing :

I have two pages,

- One with a list of suppliers
- If I click on one of the suppliers I am supposed to get to the second page which contains all the users of the selected supplier.

Here is my code,

**Page SelectSupplier :**

```cs
var link = '@Url.Action("UserManagement", "Home", new { GB = @ViewBag.GB, id = "code" })';

link = link.replace("code", listSuppliers[i].Item2);

suppliersTable.row.add([
  "<form action='" + link + "'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>" + listSuppliers[i].Item3 + " account(s)</button></form>" //Number of accounts, clickable to see all accounts
]).draw(false);
```

**Controller :**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserManagement(string GB, string id)
{...
return View();
}
```

The problem is that when I click on my supplier, the page **UserManagement** displays: "*This page isn't working if the problem continues contact the site owner HTTP Error 405*"

I really don't get it, can anybody help me ?

Comment: I think this has been answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185327/http-405-error-on-invoking-controller-method

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to create a form to go to a link? Why not just build a GET URL with a route or query string?

Anyway, it's an MVC feature to make forms POST by default. If you don't specify the method in HTML, then it's a GET. So add `method="post"` to your form.

You can see what the browser sends in F12, under Network.

Comment: Thats not really answering his question. A lot has changed from .net to .net core MVC, and sometimes just a clear answer is what's required.

Comment: @Mike HTTP methods and how HTML forms use those haven't changed in 30 years. Their action is marked as POST, so the solution is to mark their form method as POST, or it'll default to GET.

Comment: thanks for editing your answer to make it clearer.